# como filtrar números positivos y negativos, aparte sumarlos en la función

Tags: javascript

si ejecuto este código me da como resultado numero negativos y lo necesito en positivos

#### enunciado

> Crear una función que reciba como parametro un arreglo. el mismo debe
> efectuar la suma solo de los numeros positivos

```js
let numeros = [-45,55,-78,5,7,99,5,4,-888,77,4,23,14,45,78,44,56]
let suma =0

const filtradoDeNumeros = numeros.filter((valor)=> valor > 0)

for (let i = 0; i < filtradoDeNumeros.length; i++) {
  suma += numeros[i]
}

console.log ("la suma es: " + suma)
```

Comment: lo puedes hacer con bucles iterando el elemento y sumando cada iteración retornando el resultado. Mas no se puede ayudar, ya que es un ejercicio y está para que aprendas a programar, si te lo solucionásemos estaríamos generándote un problema a futuro. Si realizas el código pero te salta una excepcion que no comprendas o no realiza la suma correctamente, en ese momento si que sería adecuado que realizases una pregunta.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo,muestranos que has intentado, consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: osea lo que necesito esuna pista de por donde empezar

Comment: la pista la tienes, funcion, parametro, iterar, sumar, retornar

Comment: esto es lo que e echo

Comment: Gracias Hugo por seguir las directrices del sitio. He revertido tu último cambio porque has añadido el código de la respuesta y hace que si lees la pregunta y luego la respuesta no tenga mucho sentido: el código de la pregunta hacía lo correcto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que dentro del bucle estás sumando los números del array original, y no del que has filtrado. A veces cuando uno aprende es fácil equivocarse con cosas que parecen obvias para otros, tranquilo, a todos nos pasa.

Reemplaza

```
suma += numeros[i]
```

por

```
suma += filtradoDeNumeros[i]
```

Answer (score 4):

en lugar de usar un filtro, en este caso lo que necesitas es un reduce.
a este metodo le pasas una funcion que recibira como parametros el valor total y el valor actual, en ella compruebas si el valor es positivo y lo sumas. tambien es necesario pasarle al metodo un valor inicial 0 para evitar sumar el primer valor en caso de ser negativo.

```js
const numeros = [-45,55,-78,5,7,99,5,4,-888,77,4,23,14,45,78,44,56];
let suma = numeros.reduce(sumarPositivos,0);
console.log("suma: " + suma);

function sumarPositivos(total, actual){
    return actual > 0 ? total + actual : total;
}
```